Systemd kills all background processes after ssh session ends despite all the typical solutions
I have tried almost every solution on Stack Exchange (except for nohup; it seems like that is not an ideal loophole), but Systemd still kills my background processes.
I also tried starting a Tmux session as a service using this question, but the processes started in Tmux still get killed after SSH is disconnected.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, the desktop version. My monitor is disconnected, but I have not set up headless mode, so I am wondering if, in the desktop version, I have to keep the monitor connected after local login. Disconnecting the monitor could cause Systemd to infer that no user is active, per this email archive.


I have tried almost every solution on Stack Exchange (except for nohup; it seems like that is not an ideal loophole), but Systemd still kills my background processes.

I'm going to repeat the same solution again, regardless:

Run loginctl enable-linger <user> to tell systemd-logind to always keep that user's 'systemd --user' service manager around. I don't recall if this also suppresses killing of "session" processes – if it does, great – but that's not the main reason for this suggestion.
By default, systemd-logind starts a per-user service manager when that user has any sessions, and stops it when the last session is closed. With the linger flag set, it'll start the service manager on boot and stop it on shutdown.

Either a) use a recent version of tmux which integrates with systemd, and starts each pane in its own systemd "scope" (as can be seen in /proc/self/cgroup inside tmux),
or b) Use systemd-run --user to start your long-lived processes under the service manager (and therefore outside of your logon session),
or c) Write service units in ~/.config/systemd/user/ for the long-running processes and systemctl --user start them.



Disconnecting the monitor could cause Systemd to infer that no user is active, per this email archive.

The linked post has nothing to do with monitors. It is about serial console (RS232 port) sessions.

I tried all those solutions, but all processes get killed indiscriminately after about an hour of the user logging out. I even tried using nohup, but it did not work.

"After about an hour" does not sound like anything built-in to systemd – all standard systemd mechanisms would kill the processes when the user logged out. How did you determine that it is in fact systemd killing your processes?

I have this minimum script running with the other bg processes, and it also gets killed. I can't find any system logs explaining why processes are being killed.
`#!/bin/bash
while true
do
Echo current date to stdout
echo 'date'
Echo 'error!' to stderr
echo 'error!' >&2
sleep 1
done`

Right, so I suspect you've been chasing the wrong thing the entire time. Attach a strace -p <pid> to the bash process – or to something like a sleep 999h process, even – and check the last few lines of strace when it gets killed.

I should add that I did not have this problem a week ago. It started after I rebooted the system (the monitor was disconnected).

@aneeqaf Do I understand your comments to mean that you're running a shell loop that outputs to stdout and stderr every second, and this runs after the ssh session is gone, so the process's stdout/stderr is no longer connected to a device?

@SottoVoce I redirect the output to a file. I am running this for diagnosis purposes, along with other heavy processes that are getting killed after an hr of logging out. If I stay logged in, everything runs fine.

@grawity, strace seems to have been killed in the middle of its output. This is what the last few lines look like,
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x5d66e62b5d70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_

Try to run strace from an active session as a different user. That is, connect as user 1, run some program, separately connect as user 2 (or as root), attach sudo strace -p <pid>, then disconnect from user 1 while staying connected as user 2. And as another thing to try, if you suspect systemd, then try a systemctl --user log-level debug as user 1 (before running the thing and disconnecting) and watch logs (journalctl -f) as user 2. (If that gives nothing, then systemd-logind logs with systemctl service-log-level systemd-logind debug would be the next thing to try.)
